# ¿Declarar variable escalar?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo este código y cuando trato de modificar presionando el botón **Modificar**, me dice que debo declarar la variable escalar **@Cedula**, que por cierto es la que uso como identificador para realizar las modificaciones.

```
private void BtnModificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Conexion.Conectar();

        if (txtCedula.Text != "")
        {
            string sexo = string.Empty;
            if (rdHombre.Checked)
            {
                sexo = "Hombre";
            }
            else if (rdMujer.Checked)
            {
                sexo = "Mujer";
            }

            string actualizar = "UPDATE DatosEstudiantes SET Nombre=@Nombre, Apellidos=@Apellidos, Carrera=@Carrera, LugarNacimiento=@LugarNacimiento, FechaNacimiento=@FechaNacimiento, Sexo=@Sexo, Direccion=@Direccion, Telefono=@Telefono, Provincia=@Provincia, LiceoProcede=@LiceoProcede,Foto=@Foto WHERE Cedula=@Cedula";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(actualizar, Conexion.Conectar());

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", txtNombres.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apellidos", txtApellidos.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Carrera", cmbCarrera.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LugarNacimiento", txtLugarNacimiento.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaNacimiento", cmbFechaNacimiento.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sexo", sexo);
            /*cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EstadoCivil", .SqlDbType.Date);*/
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Direccion", txtDireccion.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", txtTelefono.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Provincia", cmbProvincia.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LiceoProcede", txtLiceoProcede.Text);
         
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foto", pbImagen.Image);

            // Asignando el valor de la imagen

            // Stream usado como buffer
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            // Se guarda la imagen en el buffer
            pbImagen.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            // Se extraen los bytes del buffer para asignarlos como valor para el 
            // parámetro.
            cmd.Parameters["@Foto"].Value = ms.GetBuffer();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Actualización Exitosa");
        }            
}
```

Comment: El error te da pq no estás añadiendo a cedula como parámetro a la consulta como haces con el resto de los campos

Comment: Y su tipo de dato es un string

Comment: @Japv Amigo no,cuando añado la linea: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cedula", txtCedula.Text);                                    .El programa se queda algo trabado y me dice un mensaje "se agotó el tiempo de espera.

Comment: Pues entonces entonces modifica la propiedad timeout,pon cmd.TimeOut = valor y vas probando con números mayores

Comment: @Japv Aun así se toma su tiempo, pero sale el mismo error.

Comment: Cuantos registros tiene esa tabla

Comment: @Japv 12. Pero como puedes ver hay uno que no lo utilizo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117225/discussion-between-japv-and-luis).

Comment: Hola, podrías hacerme saber si la respuesta dada te sirvio

Comment: @Japv Si,gracias,aunque no a la primera,pero quité unos campos de la BD y probé y probé. Al final volví a añadir esos campos y funcionó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He aquí como lo tengo ya funcionando:

```
  private void BtnModificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string sexo = string.Empty;

        if (rdHombre.Checked)
        {
            sexo = "Hombre";
        }
        else if (rdMujer.Checked)
        {
            sexo = "Mujer";
        }



        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = MEGATRON;Initial Catalog = RegistroEstudiantesUASD;Integrated Security=True;"))
        {

            string cadena = "UPDATE DatosEstudiantes SET  Nombre=@Nombre, Apellidos=@Apellidos, Carrera=@Carrera, LugarNacimiento=@LugarNacimiento, FechaNacimiento=@FechaNacimiento,  Direccion=@Direccion, Telefono=@Telefono, Provincia=@Provincia, LiceoProcede=@LiceoProcede, Foto=@Foto, Sexo=@Sexo WHERE Cedula=@Cedula";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cadena, con);

            //Lleno los parámetros 




            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cedula", txtCedula.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", txtNombres.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apellidos", txtApellidos.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Carrera", cmbCarrera.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LugarNacimiento", txtLugarNacimiento.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaNacimiento", cmbFechaNacimiento.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sexo", sexo);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Direccion", txtDireccion.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", txtTelefono.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Provincia", cmbProvincia.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LiceoProcede", txtLiceoProcede.Text);





            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foto", pbImagen.Image);



            // Asignando el valor de la imagen

            // Stream usado como buffer
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            // Se guarda la imagen en el buffer
            pbImagen.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            // Se extraen los bytes del buffer para asignarlos como valor para el 
            // parámetro.
            cmd.Parameters["@Foto"].Value = ms.GetBuffer();


            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 12000;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu código no creas el objeto conexión y no abres el mismo.

Deberías poner esto:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion)
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(actualizar, con);

   //Lleno los parámetros 

   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       
}
```

Se crea el **objeto SqlConnection**, el cual establece la conexión con la base de datos, esta conexión debe recibir como parámetro la cadena de la conexión la cual guarda los datos de la conexión, como puede ser nombre de la base de datos, servidor, usuario y contraseña en caso de tenerla, este **objeto SqlConnection** se crea dentro del **using** para así garantizar su destrucción una vez que se salga del mismo **using**, posteriormente se crea el **SqlCommand** recibiendo como parámetro el comando a ejecutar, que en este caso es una **sentencia update** y además recibe el objeto conexión, se abre la conexión y se ejecuta el **update**.

Aquí un ejemplo de una cadena de conexión:

**"Database=BD;SServia.;user=usuario;password=clave"**